# In "set of reasons that" what does *that* modify?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses, there-is

Suppose that there is a survey of people asking them their reasons for thinking or behaving a certain way. While analyzing the survey results, a researcher may discuss all the different reasons the respondents put forth, and compare reasons that were shared by multiple people. The researcher then writes:

> There is a common set of reasons that are compelling.

But I have a quibble with this: the sentence starts out with the singular subject *set* (thus the matching *there is*), but surprises the reader by making *that* modify *reasons* instead of *set*, as clearly indicated through the use of *are* instead of *is* that would match the singular *set*.

Are my instincts correct? If so, what rule of grammar is this violating?

*Bonus: please suggest a good title. It's hard to come up with a title when I don't know the answer, yet. I realized that "Sentence grammaticality" is not a good title, but I don't know if the current one is an improvement.*

Comment: Your examples are in the form of an existential construction; and the grammatical subject of an existential construction is the dummy pronoun "there". The expression "that is/are compelling" is an integrated relative clause, and that relative clause can be considered to be modifying either the noun "reasons" or the nominal "common set".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence. Let's parse it logically:

> There is a set.
>
> The set contains reasons.
>
> The reasons are compelling.

The grammar tracks the logic:

> There is [singular copular verb agreeing with singular predicate nominative *set*] a common set [singular predicate nominative] of reasons [prepositional phrase modifying *set*] that [beginning of a restrictive clause modifying *reasons*] are [plural copular verb agreeing with the actual subject, *reasons*] compelling.

Simply put, the *set isn't compelling*. The *reasons are*.

TITLE: *Should a verb agree in number with a collective noun or its subparts?*